# Regex for at most one infix 00 and one infix 11

Tags: regex

I have a bit-sequence, which can also start with 0's. I want to write a regex, that only matches sequences, that contains 00 <= one time and 11 <= one time.

My attempt is `^([01](?!(?:[^(00|11)]*(00|11){2})))*$`, which I tried with [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/on5k9q/1). Sadly this doesn't really work.

For example it doesn't matches `010000` (which is correct) but does match `01000100`, which obviously should not be detected.

Comment: Why do you have square brackets here? `[^(00|11)]`

Comment: `[^chars]` matches a single character that isn't any of the `chars`.

Comment: Do you have to do this with regex?

Comment: @Barmar sadly yes

Comment: You'll probably need to use negative lookaround to match exactly once in the entire string.

Comment: Perhaps like https://regex101.com/r/E1xFZA/1/

Comment: I tried it by using negative lookahead, but there is where I stuck and that's as far as I managed to go... And I'm not an regex pro :/

Comment: @Thefourthbird yeah, that looks right to me! The only question is, if it's possible do make it a bit nicer :D

Answer (score 2):

In your pattern, this part `[^(00|11)]` uses a negated character class which will match any other than the listed and can be written as `[^01|)(]`

One option is to use 2 negative lookaheads to assert that 00 and 11 do not occur more than 2 times and 1 positive lookahead to assert that there is 11.

```
^(?!(?:[01]*11){2})(?!(?:[01]*00){2})(?=[01]*11)[01]*00[01]*$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?!(?:[01]*11){2})` Negative lookahead, assert what is on the right is not 2 times 11
- `(?!(?:[01]*00){2})` Negative lookahead, assert what is on the right is not 2 times 00
- `(?=[01]*11)` Positive lookahead, assert 11
- `[01]*00[01]*` Match 0+ times 0 or 1, then 00 followed by 0+ times 0 or 1
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sl55tv/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can think of it as a password validation

`^(?!.*00.*00)(?!.*11.*11)(?=.*00)(?=.*11)[01]+$`

https://regex101.com/r/nIDjNq/1

Explained

```
 ^                     # BOS
 (?! .* 00 .* 00 )     # Not 2 of  '00'
 (?! .* 11 .* 11 )     # Not 2 of  '11'
 (?= .* 00 )           # Has a '00'
 (?= .* 11 )           # Has a '11'
 [01]+                 # Match multiple  0 or 1
 $                     # EOS
```

A benchmark *fwiw*

```
Regex1:   ^(?!.*00.*00)(?!.*11.*11)(?=.*00)(?=.*11)[01]+$
Options:  < m >
Completed iterations:   50  /  50     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   4
Elapsed Time:    1.49 s,   1493.59 ms,   1493587 µs
Matches per sec:   133,905


Regex2:   ^(?!(?:[01]*11){2})(?!(?:[01]*00){2})(?=[01]*11)[01]*00[01]*$
Options:  < m >
Completed iterations:   50  /  50     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   4
Elapsed Time:    2.62 s,   2623.45 ms,   2623447 µs
Matches per sec:   76,235
```